# Implementation of OnClickListener method on a custom view

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener

I'm having an issue with dynamic view creation and OnClickListener. I want my dynamic view to do things when I click on the it. To do so, I've implemented OnClickListener:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public abstract class ChordDiagram extends View implements OnClickListener {

...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {       
//it's gonna be implemented by its sons
}
}
```

Then, I have another class:

```
public class KeyboardChordDiagram extends ChordDiagram {

...

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Here's gonna do something :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I'm kinda new to Android and I suspect it has something to do with the context, but I really don't know what it is.
I also tried to implement OnClickListener on the activity class and set the my real event to the activity method, but it didn't work either.

Comment: have you called the setOnClickListener() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add that line in every constructor of your class: `this.setOnClickListerner(this);`

For example:

```
public abstract class ChordDiagram extends View implements OnClickListener
{
    public ChordDiagram(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        this.setOnClickListerner(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //it's gonna be implemented by its sons
    }
}
```